# Clone Element and Append to end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML template which looks like this:

```
<div id="amznplist">
    <div id="amznpitem">
        <span>
            <img src="%%Produktbild%%" alt="%%Produkttitel%%"><div id="amzntitle">%%Produkttitel%%</div><div id="amzprice">%%Produktpreis%%</div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I try to archive is to load the entire html, copy the #amznpitem item, run through my response (data) and populate each li element with the data and add it to the end. What happens is that only one element is added to #amznplist. This is my current code.

```
            var li = html.find('#amznpitem').clone();
            html.find('#amznpitem').remove();
            var ul = html.find('#amznplist');

            $.each(data, function (index, values) {
                li.find('#amzntitle').text(values['title'][0]);
                li.find('a').attr('href', values['url'][0]);
                li.find('img').attr('src', values['img'][0]);
                li.find('img').attr('alt', values['title'][0]);
                li.find('#amzprice').text(values['lowest_price'][0]);
                $(ul).append(li);

            });
            $('#result').html(html);
```

Comment: use classes instead of ids - ids are meant to be unique and as such jquery will only fetch the first element with that id it finds

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating over the response data in your loop, you are always accessing the first element - `values...[0]`. Use the index that you have available in the `each` function to pass the values from the current iteration

```
    $.each(data, function (index, values) {
            li.find('#amzntitle').text(values['title'][index]);
            li.find('a').attr('href', values['url'][index]);
            li.find('img').attr('src', values['img'][index]);
            li.find('img').attr('alt', values['title'][index]);
            li.find('#amzprice').text(values['lowest_price'][index]);
            $(ul).append(li);

        });
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not the problem I try to solve. The [0] is important because the json is kinda weird at this point and I need to get the first child of values['title] and so on.